# Java Swing remove LAF style from checkbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, look-and-feel

I would like to remove the blue thing aroud the LAF JCheckbox :

[image]

How can I do ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to do it for all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Icon is part of the LAF.

If you don't like the default Icons, then you can always provide your own:

```
checkBox.setIcon(...);
checkBox.setSelectedIcon(...);
```